# Multiple conditions when using guards in haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to determine a valid move. A move must meet two conditions to make it a valid move. The first condition is making sure there is no existing piece already in the position where I want to move, the second condition is making sure I will score a point when I make this move.

I have completed the code for the first condition, but I don't know how to follow this on with the second condition. Perhaps the reason why its difficult is because it returns a Bool, which needs to be set at True or False when one of the other conditions is met. For example

```
valid :: Piece -> Pieces -> Bool
valid p [] = True
valid p (x:xs) | getPos(p) == getPos(x) = False
                       | otherwise = valid p xs
```

So as you can see, I have done the code for the first condition, now how do I add in the second condition?

Something like

```
valid :: Piece -> Pieces -> Bool
valid p [] = True
valid p (x:xs) | getPos(p) == getPos(x) = False
                       | otherwise = valid p xs
                       && ...
```

But then again, this function will stop if the first condition either fails or passes. Whats the work around for this?

EDIT: Declarations

```
data Piece = Piece Position Player
type Pieces = [Piece]
```

EDIT: getPos

getPos is a function that retrieves the position of a piece

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could move the test for a vacant location to a helper function (`vacant`, say) and write your other conditions in `valid`, such as with an additional `score` function:

```
valid :: Piece -> Pieces -> Bool
valid p xs = vacant p xs && score p xs > 0

vacant :: Piece -> Pieces -> Bool
vacant p [] = True
vacant p (x:xs)
  | getPos p == getPos x = False
  | otherwise = vacant p xs

score :: Piece -> Pieces -> Int
score p xs = error "TODO"
```

You can also express `vacant` more simply, avoiding explicit recursion:

```
import Data.List (notElem)

vacant p xs = getPos p `notElem` map getPos xs
```

However, I would guess that computing the score relies on the fact that the move was possible. So you might find that it’s an improvement to roll this into a single function that tests for a valid move with a positive score and returns a `Maybe`:

```
score :: Piece -> Pieces -> Maybe Int
score p xs
  | getPos p `notElem` map getPos xs = let
    computedScore = error "TODO"
    in if computedScore > 0
      then Just computedScore
      else Nothing

  | otherwise = Nothing
```

Now you can pattern-match on the result of `score`: if you get `Nothing`, then the move was invalid or didn’t result in a positive score; if you get `Just s`, then the move was valid and resulted in the score `s`.